# How to get Multiple image uri from gallery with intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, intentfilter

I want to get multiple image URI using intent filter without implements a whole custom filechooser.

To get the URI of a single image I use

```
private void openImage() {
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, FILE_REQ_CODE);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        }

    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intentData) {
        try {
            Uri tmp = intentData.getData();
            filePath = getRealFilePathFromURI(tmp);
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        }

    }
```

That works fine...

However I don't know how to get multiple selection using Intent filters.

How could I get multiple URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means to get multiple images, at least not through standard `Intent` actions like `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, so I must integrate a file manager. Damn! Google should improve the file management. Thanks for the answer.